# display floats with precision of 3

Tags: java, android, string-formatting

I've been struggling with this problem for a while. I have numbers that are shown in a TextView. In this textview, I would only like the float to be shown with a precision of 3 as there is only room for 3 numbers. Here are some input - output examples of what I am trying to achieve:

```
1       -> 1.00
0.34   -> 0.34
-12.34  -> -12.3
123.45  -> 123
```

The input will always be rounded to the nearest hundredth.
I've tried using String.format and even making a custom format.
Currently I have logic to figure out the formatting, but there must be a one liner:

```
    float abs_d = Math.abs(my_float);

    String dist = "";
    if (abs_d < 10) {
        dist = String.format("%1.2f", d);
    }
    else if (abs_d < 100) {
        dist = String.format("%2.1f", d);
    }
    else {
        dist = String.format("%3.f",d);
    }
    my_text_view.setText(dist);
```

Perhaps there is a sneaky way to do it using the TextView? You can specify the pixel width, but how about the character width (but even then, would i accept a negative sign)? I imagine there should be some Java library to do this.

Comment: That doesn't work. `99.96` comes out as `100.0` instead of `100`.

Comment: My last comment assumes `%f` rounds (as it should to be useful). If it rounds up or rounds to even, the fix is to replace `10` with `9.5` and `100` with `95.5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ikegami @Jack thanks for the conversation and suggestions.
This seems to get the functionality for which I'm searching:

```
    String str = "999";
    DecimalFormat f = null;
    if (abs_d < 1000) {
        if (abs_d < 1) {
            f = new DecimalFormat("@@");
            str = f.format(d);
        }
        else {
            f = new DecimalFormat("@@@");
            str = f.format(d);
        }
    }

    my_text_view.setText(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

I take it you've tried things like using [DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)?

Comment: DecimalFormat works well, but i'm loosing my negative sign. DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("@@#");
  System.out.println("format: "+f.format(abs_d));. But i guess i could always just test before formatting.

Comment: Add a negative subpattern that inserts a negative sign?

Comment: @Ian, Becuse you're passing `abs_d` instead of `my_float` and because you didn't include a `-` in your pattern? `@@@;-@@@`

Comment: @ikegami Ah yeah i missed that. It seems to work almost perfect. However 12.98 is changed to 13 (i want 13.0). I need @@# opposed to @@@ because 0.93 will format to 0.930. Perhaps, i'm too picky?

Comment: @Ian, from reading the docs, I thought `@@#` would lead to 0.93 (min 2 significant) and `@@@` would lead to 0.930` (min 3 significant). Use whichever one gives the result you want.

Comment: @ikagami correct, @@# formates 0.93 well. However, @@# formats 12.98 as 13 and not the desired 13.0. See below for what I'm settling.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there's a one liner. Put the logic in a function called `format_float` and use

```
my_text_view.setText(format_float(my_float));
```